# Diffusion equation for Brownian motion with a systematic drift component

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

I know, that BM formula

$$X_{i+1} = X_{i}+\sqrt{\delta t}Z_i,$$   $$Z_i\sim N(0,1),$$

with $X_0\equiv0$ leads to Diffusion equation $$u_t=-\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}$$

for marginal distributions in $X_i=X(t),t=i\delta t,$ in the limit case $\delta t\to 0$.

I want to derive Diffusion equation for Brownian motion with a systematic drift component, i.e.

$$X_{i+1} = X_{i}+\delta tX_{i}+\sqrt{\delta t}Z_i,$$

using Chapmann-Kolmogorov equation and Taylor expression.

How can i derive this? What is the answer?

Any explanation is very appreciated.

$$$$

To my calculations:

Let density function for BM $\pi_t (x)$ in time $t$ be defined as
$$\pi_t (x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} exp \left (\frac{-x^2}{2t}\right).$$

According to properties of BW increments we consider Chapmann-Kolmogorov equation as follow:
$$\pi_{t+\delta t} (x')=\int {\frac{exp \left (\frac{-(x'-x)^2}{2\delta t}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi \delta t}}\pi_t (x) dx}.$$

$x = x'+ \Delta x, \Rightarrow dx\rightarrow d \Delta x,$
$$\Rightarrow \pi_{t+\delta t} (x')= \int {\frac{exp \left (\frac{-(\Delta x)^2}{2\delta t}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi \delta t}}\pi_t (x'+\Delta x) d\Delta x}.$$

Since $\Delta x = \delta tX_{i}+\sqrt{\delta t}Z_i$ we have Taylor expansion:
$$\pi_t (x'+\Delta x) = \pi_t (x') + \frac{d\pi_t(x')}{dx} \Delta x + ... + O(\Delta x^4).$$

Then
$$\pi_{t+\delta t} (x')= \int {\frac{exp \left (\frac{-(\Delta x)^2}{2\delta t}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi \delta t}}\pi_t (x'+\Delta x) d\Delta x}$$

$$=\pi_t (x')+\frac{d\pi_t}{dx} \delta t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2\pi_t}{dx^2}\delta t+\frac{1}{6} \frac{d^3\pi_t}{dx^3}3 \delta t^2 + O(\delta t^3);$$

$$\frac{\pi_{t+\delta t} (x') - \pi_t (x')}{\delta t}=\frac{d\pi_t}{dx} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2\pi_t}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^3\pi_t}{dx^3}\delta t + O(\delta t^2);$$

$\delta t \rightarrow 0:$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\pi_t (x')=\frac{d\pi_t}{dx} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2\pi_t}{dx^2}.$$